# Content Management Systems with W3 Compliance

Tags: content-management-system, w3c-validation

I am looking for Content Management Systems that comply with W3 standards in HTML. I prefer those that are coded in Java or PHP (preferably Java). Any ideas where I can get such information? I checked on http://www.cmsmatrix.org and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems‎ but they don't tell if the CMS's actually comply with W3 standards.

Answer (score 0):

W3C published [many standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/).

I’d say that most of these standards can be relevant for CMS, e.g., [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/), [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-core/), [ATAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/ATAG10/), [WCAG](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/), [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/), etc.

And most of these technologies/standards/best-practices would be implemented in the **frontend/backend theme** (aka. template). So any CMS which allows you to use custom themes should do the job.

If or which default themes of which CMS follow W3C standards is a question which would be off-topic for Stack Overflow. You already found lists of CMS; select the Java/PHP ones and check their default theme for whichever criteria are relevant to you.